# Update one field in blob in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

I have one blob in a table which has following form :-

```
[{"name":"CREATED_BY_JOHN","description":"","alg":"None","srcPort":"","dstPort":"2345","disableTimeout":false}]
```

I want to upgrade the blobs "alg":"None" field to "alg":"null"

How to do that in MySQL

Can I do something like this :-

```
Update ApplicationEntity set protocolBlob='%"alg":"null"%' where protocolBlob like '%"alg":"None"%';
```

Comment: A blob in MySQL is binary, and AFAIK there is no way to do the kind of JSON manipulation you want directly.  If you were storing your JSON text as a JSON type, then you _might_ be able to update it with MySQL's JSON functions.  If you stick with a blob, you will probably have to read it into your app language, and update it there.

Comment: To add to @TimBiegeleisen comment you can only use JSON datatype if you are using MySQL 5.7+.. But JSON functions also work on VARCHAR, CHAR or anny TEXT datatypes.. But the JSON datatype has a added feature to ensure the inserted/updated JSON string is valid JSON